# Add, don't replace, icon to mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add an icon to mouse when they hover html element, so that I could hint to the user, that they can right click.

I don't want to replace the default cursor, because they differ on platform and don't really need to replace the default mouse icon itself.

Comment: Have a look here. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Comment: @Dula all those replace the the cursor. I'm interested in ADDing to the cursor. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `mousemove` event listener on the element which you want to show the custom cursor over that gets the relative x and y coordinates of the mouse to the element and applies them to the `top` and `left` style properties of the cursor:

```js
element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const [x, y] = [e.pageX - rect.left, e.pageY - Math.abs(rect.top) + window.scrollY]
  cursor.style.display = "block";
  cursor.style.left = x + "px";  
  cursor.style.top = y + "px";
})

element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
  cursor.style.display = "none"; //hide the custom cursor when they leave the element
})
```

```css
#element{
  height:1200px;
  width:600px;
  background-color:black;
  position:relative;
}

#cursor{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"><div id="cursor">right click!</div></div>
```

Keep in mind this solution requires the container element to be relatively positioned, since the cursor is absolutely positioned.

Comment: Omg. Learned something additionally new from this example. `id='cursor'` is accessible without explicitly creating the element! :D

Comment: @MihkelL. BTW, the previous version of my answer did not support scrolling (e.g, after the user scrolled, it would break). It should work now 